# Setting OnClick for NavigationDrawer Items in android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigationview, android-jetpack-navigation

I have made a navigation drawer with some 20-25 items in them. Its path is res/menu/navigation_menu.xml. In my Main Activity I wrote the below code which in my best knowledge till now is the default code for navigation drawers:

```
findViewById(R.id.imageMenu).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        });

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);

        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.navHostFragment);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller, @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
                tv1.setText(destination.getLabel());
            }
        });
```

here 'R.id.imageMenu' is that 3 horizontal lined image which opens the drawer.
This is my activity_main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:background="#0097A7">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageMenu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_white_24dp">
            </ImageView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mainTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="All docs"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF">
            </TextView>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/mbib"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_more_vert_white_24dp">
            </ImageButton>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/navHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/main">
        </fragment>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cv1"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="7.5dp"
            android:background="#47433F">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/mbrl1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_height="65dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mbtv1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_image_white_24dp"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="      Import from Gallery">
                </TextView>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/mbrl2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="65dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mbtv2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_picture_as_pdf_white_24dp"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="      Import PDF">
                </TextView>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/layout_navigation_header"
        android:layout_gravity="start">
    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In my navigation drawer items, I have 2 items named **Rate Us** and **Share** for which I have not defined any fragment because for them I want to do some other work (like for Rate Us I will be opening my app link in playstore).

**My Question**:
I want that my navigation drawer should work as it is working now except when **Rate Us** or **Share** item is clicked. In that case (it is not doing anything as there in no fragment for them) I want to open my app link in playstore or some other work. How can I achieve this? Thank You.

If I am missing on any part of code then please tell me I will update my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a custom `NavigationItemSelectedListener` but by calling `setNavigationItemSelectedListener`, you are removing the original listener.

In this case you have to trigger the default behavior by calling `NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected()`.

Something like:

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.xxxxx -> {
                    // handle click
                    true
                }
            }

             NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(it, navController)
             drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
             true
        }
```

Comment: The code worked like a charm @Gabriele Mariotti. Thank you very much for your help. An upvote and I am accepting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

okay for **rate** && **Share**

```
   @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.rateus) {
     Intent rateIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + context.getPackageName())); 
      startActivity(rateIntent);


    } else if (id == R.id.share) {
     //just an example
     String message = "Text I want to share.";
     Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
     share.setType("text/plain");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Title of the dialog the system will open"));


    } else if (id == R.id.anything) {

    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help @Wini but for your code I have to write if else for all 20-25 items in my navigation drawer.  But I just wanted to write the if else for rate us and share. For all other items I wanted the default behaviour. Gabriele Mariotti's answer explains exactly what I needed. I will definitely upvote your answer too for your help as I can use the part of code that you gave for share and rate. Thanx